# Applescript Editor typing text in an e-mail

Tags: macos, email, applescript

I wanted to make an Applescript program that allows you to send an e-mail.
I made this but it won't work.
Can anyone help me out?

Code:

```
set answer1 to text returned of (display dialog "Type here your message" default answer "" buttons {"OK"} default button 1)
set answer2 to text returned of (display dialog "Type the e-mail you want to send to" default answer "" buttons {"OK"} default button 1)
set answer3 to text returned of (display dialog "Type your subject" default answer "" buttons {"OK"} default button 1)
tell application "Mail"
    open "new"
    delay 1
    keystroke answer1
    tell application "System Events" to key code 48
    repeat 3 times
        keystroke answer3
        tell application "System Events" to key code 48
        keystroke answer2
        open "send"
    end repeat
end tell
```

Hope anyone of you can find out what I can do.

Comment: You certainly don't need to talk to "System Events". Open Mail.app with AppleScript-Editor to see it's scripting dictionary. After that search SO for more.

Comment: "It won't work" doesn't tell us much. What happens and what do you want or expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as mentioned, 'System Events' is not the way to go. Here's an approach to what I think you're trying to do:

```
set answer1 to text returned of (display dialog "Type here your message" default answer "" buttons {"OK"} default button 1)
set answer2 to text returned of (display dialog "Type the e-mail you want to send to" default answer "" buttons {"OK"} default button 1)
set answer3 to text returned of (display dialog "Type your subject" default answer "" buttons {"OK"} default button 1)
tell application "Mail"
    set myMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:answer3, content:answer1}
    tell myMessage
        make new to recipient with properties {name:answer2, address:answer2}
        send
    end tell
end tell
```